# Prestashop update fail - PrestaShopDatabaseException

Tags: sql, prestashop

I tried 1click update on PrestaShop and failed.
Tried restore and failed.
Dont know where is problem.
Here is error message.
Thank you for help

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]
Table 'd90629_xxx.ps_shop_url' doesn't exist


SELECT s.id_shop, CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri) AS uri, su.domain, su.main
                    FROM ps_shop_url su
                    LEFT JOIN ps_shop s ON (s.id_shop = su.id_shop)
                    WHERE (su.domain = 'xxx.com' OR su.domain_ssl = 'xxx.com')
                        AND s.active = 1
                        AND s.deleted = 0
                    ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(su.physical_uri, su.virtual_uri)) DESC

at line 639 in file classes/db/Db.php
634.            WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
635.        }
636.        elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS'))
637.        {
638.            if ($sql)
639.                throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
640.            throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
641.        }
642.    }
643. 
644.    /**
DbCore->displayError - [line 333 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 509 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->executeS - [line 329 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 97 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```

Comment: Are you connected as the correct user?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as that the d90629_xxx.ps_shop_url table does not exist, did you take a look in the DB for it? Perhaps using phpmyadmin or themysql console?

If it is not there you can import it back from a previous backup.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to the upgrade.

This is an error you have after failing to upgrade on the page index.php (`// require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]`)

To find the original error, you need to check the server logs

Comment: thank you for answer.
I have this on line 27:


27. require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
28. Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();

Comment: this is not an error!! the best way is to restore the backup and upgrade again